# How to get different between two dates (in a form) in days

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have this `javascript` code to get the difference between two dates **inside a `form` tag in html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function dueDate(){
            var date1=document.getElementById("date1").value;
            var date2=document.getElementById("date2").value;
            var diffDays = parseInt((date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
            alert(diffDays)             
        }
 </script>
```

This is my`html` code (and two date selectors are inside a `form`)

```
<div class="login-form">
        <form name="login" method="POST">
             <table cellspacing="10">
                <tr>
                    <td id="text">Book Return Due Date:</td>
                    <td><input id="date1" type="date" name="username"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="text">Current Date:</td>
                    <td><input id="date2" type="date" name="password"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="text"><input id="button1" type="submit" value="Check for Due" onclick="dueDate()"></td>
                    <td><input id="button2" type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
                </tr>

             </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**But I'm getting an alert as "NaN". Please help me**

Comment: Note that you can try the recently added [*valueAsDate* property](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#dom-htmlinputelement-valueasdate) for date inputs, though support may be limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript has Date() object for manipulating dates, You can try this:

```
var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById("date1").value);
var date2= new Date(document.getElementById("date2").value);
var diffDays = Math.round((date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need date objects, not just the string values returned from the inputs, to be able to subtract one date from the other

```js
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', dueDate);

function dueDate() {
  var date1 = document.getElementById("date1").value;
  var date2 = document.getElementById("date2").value;
  var obj1  = new Date(date1);
  var obj2  = new Date(date2);
  
  
  var diffDays = (obj2 - obj1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  alert(diffDays)
}
```

```html
<div class="login-form">
  <form name="login" method="POST">
    <table cellspacing="10">
      <tr>
        <td id="text">Book Return Due Date:</td>
        <td>
          <input id="date1" type="date" name="username">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="text">Current Date:</td>
        <td>
          <input id="date2" type="date" name="password">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="text">
          <input id="button1" type="submit" value="Check for Due">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="button2" type="reset" value="Reset">
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get value from your html, its type is string, so you should parse it to date. When you try to substract two strings it returns NAN. Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for Date.parse method.

Comment: An excellent point. Thanks. Really helpful :)